# Is there a way to add a reason comment to an inline rule-disabling comment?

Tags: eslint

Sometimes we have linting rules with good reason, but which need to be disabled for a specific line.

I would like to be able to add a comment to the disabling comment

e.g.

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line rulename because very good reasons
code.that.violates==rulename
```

Trying to do this causes problems for eslint because it thinks the rule you want to disable is called `rulename because very good reasons`

Obviously I could use a separate comment, but this comment must go before the disabling comment, otherwise the rule is only disabled for the comment line - i.e. this doesn't work

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line rulename
// because very good reasons
code.that.violates==rulename
```

Putting the comment anywhere else is very confusing for the reader

Is there a way to achieve this all in one comment? Maybe with some kind of undocumented terminator?
(I tried some obvious ones like `;`, `//` `#` )

i.e.

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line rulename ; because very good reasons
```

Better still, (assuming something like this is possible), can we *force* such a comment to be used?

Comment: Could it not be as easy as putting the explanatory comment before the comment that disables linting?

Comment: "Putting the comment anywhere else is very confusing for the reader"
Please read before commenting :)

Comment: I did read before commenting, though I chose not to explain my frame-challenge in that comment; but to be more explicit: I do not find it more confusing (personally) to have the explanation before the lint-disabling comment. Both approaches make sense, but the way I suggest lets you approximate what you want to achieve, although there may be a better answer.

Comment: Prepending the reason as David suggests seems pretty clear to me. Writing, "The following rule is disabled because..." is crystal clear. To force an explanation to exist, I guess you could add a gate to your build pipeline. But, to my mind, that kind of thing belongs in a commit message, not in the file, unless it's a truly peculiar case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-comments-1), since [ESLint 7](https://eslint.org/blog/2020/05/eslint-v7.0.0-released/):

> Configuration comments can include descriptions to explain why the
> comment is necessary. The description must come after the
> configuration and needs to be separated from the configuration by two
> or more consecutive `-` characters. For example:
>
> ```js
> // eslint-disable-next-line no-console -- Here's a description about why this configuration is necessary.
> console.log('hello');
>
> /* eslint-disable-next-line no-console --
>  * Here's a very long description about why this configuration is necessary
>  * along with some additional information
> **/
> console.log('hello');
> ```

In your case:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line rulename -- because very good reasons
code.that.violates==rulename
```

If you want to enforce this, you can use [`eslint-comments/require-description`](https://mysticatea.github.io/eslint-plugin-eslint-comments/rules/require-description.html).